# Is there any way of knowing if a document has been added to a collection in firebase using firebase functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Basically the question again:

Suppose there is a collection called 'People'.

Firestore functions can detect changes to a particular document, but is there anyway of knowing when a document(say 'Person1') is added to the collection using firebase functions?

If not, is there any alternate way to get to know when a document is added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a specific function type that only [triggers when a document gets created](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events#trigger_a_function_when_a_new_document_is_created). From the documentation comes this example of how to use it:

> ```js
> exports.createUser = functions.firestore
>     .document('users/{userId}')
>     .onCreate((snap, context) => {
>       // Get an object representing the document
>       // e.g. {'name': 'Marie', 'age': 66}
>       const newValue = snap.data();
>
>      // access a particular field as you would any JS property
>       const name = newValue.name;
>
>      // perform desired operations ...
>     });
> ```